# Plot $y = \sqrt{x + 2}$, and hence plot $y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x + 2}}$

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

> Plot $y = \sqrt{x + 2}$, and hence plot:
>
> $y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x + 2}}$

I was able to plot both of these graphs individually (the second took a while); however, the question seems to imply that once I have drawn the simpler $y = \sqrt{x + 2}$ function, I can derive the second function's graph from it. Is this correct? How would I use the first graph to plot the second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Try plotting both functions in the same graph. What similarity/symmetry can you see? Also read up on reciprocal functions.

Comment: **Hint 2:** For another helpful comparison, try plotting $1/(x+2)$ and $1/\sqrt{x+2}$ on the same graph.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Notice that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+2}}$ is the reciprocal of $\sqrt{x+2}$. A nice way to think of it is a seesaw. If one value goes up, the other goes down and vice versa. That means if $\sqrt{x+2}$ has a high value, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+2}}$ has a low value. Likewise, if $\sqrt{x+2}$ has a low value, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+2}}$ has a high value.

Comment: Also, for every $x$ the functions will yield $f\times g = 1$.